# repo: manifest.xml: What does the fetch=".." mean?

Tags: git, repository

Just took a look at CM's manifest.xml, like:

```
<remote  name="github"
       fetch=".."
       review="review.cyanogenmod.org" />
```

So what does this fetch=".." mean?

Comment: I think normally "fetch" should be a URL prefix for doing the "git fetch".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference this explanation:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/mKtph-wOx_w

It should be relative to the parent directory of the 'manifests/'

Take AOSP for example:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
fetch=".." in the manifest.xml is equal to "https://android.googlesource.com/platform/../"
```

Also, some detail about the repo manifest structure:

[git-history/v1.8.1/docs/manifest-format.txt](https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo/+/v1.8.1/docs/manifest-format.txt)

Comment: Thanks R_G. That makes sense. Yeah, I also found that manifest format, but it just says that "fetch" should be set as a prefix of "git fetch" URL.